# OnePageCRM API integration with PHP

Tags: php

I'm stuck with a piece of code which makes authentication to OnePageCRM API. I've try the sample code ([Code sample](https://github.com/OnePageCRM/php-sample/blob/master/index.php)) and, my own code but, both are getting the same response ( 401 ) with the following response in JSON format:

```
{"error_name":"authorization_data_not_found","status":401,"message":"Authorization
data not found","error_message":"Could not find more helpful message,
sorry.","errors":{}}
```

Just to make sure my login credentials are correct, I've test it [here](http://developer.onepagecrm.com/api_browser/).

The OnePageCRM documentation just states that 401 status is a login issue but, I can't get through the first request which requires the login data to be passed.

My caller code:

```
if( empty($this->api_login) || empty($this->api_password) ){
    LogReport::write( 'Unable to send request to OpenPageCRM. API login or password data not provided. Error throw at ' . __FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ );
    return;
}

// login to API.
$data = $this->make_api_call( 'auth/login.json', 'POST', array('login' => $this->api_login, 'password' => $this->api_password));

if( $data == null || !isset($data->data) ){
    LogReport::write( 'Unable to login to OpenPageCRM. API login or password data provided could not be validated. Error throw at ' . __FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ . 
    ' Data: ' . $data . ' | ' . $this->api_login . ' x ' . $this->api_password);
    return;
}

$uid = $data->data->uid;
$key = base64_decode($data->data->key);
```

And the handler code:

```
private function make_api_call($url, $http_method, $post_data = array(), $uid = null, $key = null) {
    require_once BASE_CLASS . 'class-log.php';

    $full_url = 'https://app.onepagecrm.com/api/v3/'.$url;

    if( !$ch = curl_init($full_url) ){
        LogReport::write( 'Unable to initialize curl at ' . __FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ );
        return;
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $http_method);

    $timestamp = time();
    $auth_data = array($uid, $timestamp, $http_method, sha1($full_url));
    $request_headers = array();

    // For POST and PUT requests we will send data as JSON
    // as with regular "form data" request we won't be able
    // to send more complex structures
    if($http_method == 'POST' || $http_method == 'PUT'){
        $request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        $json_data = json_encode($post_data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);

        $auth_data[] = sha1($json_data);
    }

    // Set auth headers if we are logged in
    if($key != null){
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', implode('.', $auth_data), $key);
        $request_headers[] = "X-OnePageCRM-UID: $uid";
        $request_headers[] = "X-OnePageCRM-TS: $timestamp";
        $request_headers[] = "X-OnePageCRM-Auth: $hash";
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);

    if( !$res = curl_exec($ch) ){
        LogReport::write('Unable to execute CUrl at ' . __FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ );
        return;
    }

    $result = json_decode($res);

    curl_close($ch);

    if($result->status > 99){
        echo "API call error: {$result->message}\n";
        LogReport::write( 'OnePageCRM API call error: ' . $result->message . ' for result ' . $res . ' at '  . __FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ );
        return null;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the cURL call to just login.json rather than auth/login.json:

```
$data = $this->make_api_call( 'login.json', 'POST', array('login' => $this->api_login, 'password' => $this->api_password));
```